# Java code to get the size of a BusinessObjects Report

Tags: java, business-objects, business-objects-sdk

I want to get the size of an SAP BusinessObjects report through Java code. My main concern is the size of the data we fetch through query, *e.g.*, `select si_id,si_name, si_size from ci_infoobjects where si_kind='webi'`

How to get the size of particular report?

Comment: Your question does not make any sense. Please provide more details.

Comment: IS BO "Business Objects", the SAP product?  http://www28.sap.com/mk/get/PPCANDG6426R_3?campaigncode=CRM-XH13-PPC-IIBOBJ2DE&kwid=TDenSN0k&mid=sTDenSN0k%7Cdc_2722p1v19626_27673719057_business+objects_p&SOURCEID=DE&s_tnt=61362:2:0

Comment: Yes it's Business Objects, the SAP Product. And my question is for BusinessObjects Java SDK. For more details on this, refer http://bukhantsov.org/2011/08/getting-started-with-businessobjects-java-sdk/#comment-23299

Comment: I got it like this

IFiles ifiles = infoObject.getFiles();
     IFile boFile = null;
     long reportSize=0;
        for (int k=0; k<ifiles.size(); k++) {
            boFile = (IFile) ifiles.get(k);
            System.out.println("Size : " + boFile.getSize());
            reportSize += boFile.getSize();
        }

Comment: I got it like this 

IFiles ifiles = infoObject.getFiles(); 
IFile boFile = null; 
long reportSize=0; 
for (int k=0; k<ifiles.size(); k++) 
{ 
boFile = (IFile) ifiles.get(k); 
reportSize += boFile.getSize(); 
} 

System.out.println("Size : " + reportSize);

Comment: That query is correct -- you should create an answer for it, so it can more easily be found if someone else is looking for the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

As Hardik Patel stated in the comments once you have a IInfoObject:

```
IFiles ifiles = object.getFiles(); 
IFile boFile = null; 
long reportSize=0; 
for (int k=0; k<ifiles.size(); k++) 
{ 
     boFile = (IFile) ifiles.get(k); 
     System.out.println("Size : " + boFile.getSize()); 
     reportSize += boFile.getSize(); 
} 
System.out.println("Size : " + reportSize);
```